# i am unable to install rvest package in rstudio

Tags: r, ubuntu, rvest, rstudio-server, ubuntu-19.04

so i want to install rvest package in my rstudio but wasn't able to as it said to install some packages on my system first ,i used this -->

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

this got executed but after this also the error was -->

```
 ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

so i tried installing then using -->

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev 
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

but these are not working the error is -->

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  libcurl4-doc libidn11-dev libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev librtmp-dev libssh2-1-dev libssl-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
Need to get 318 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,508 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 libcurl4-openssl-dev amd64 7.64.0-2ubuntu1.2
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 libcurl4-openssl-dev amd64 7.64.0-2ubuntu1.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:ffff::f 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.64.0-2ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:ffff::f 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

then i tried using both of these too -->

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev --fix-missing
```

how can this problem be solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a networking problem. It failed to connect to security,ubuntu.com.

Also not that a number of key packages *are already in the distro* so just do

```
sudo apt install r-cran-rvest
```

which works for me on 19.10 and may well too for you on 19.04 (which you should upgrade from).

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done`
`Building dependency tree`    
`Reading state information... Done`
`E: Unable to locate package r-cran-rvest`
after trying your solution this is what i get

Comment: Ok, so may be 19.04 does not have it. Do `apt-cache search r-cran-rvest` (or `r-cran-policy r-cran-rvest`).  It will likely have `r-cran-httr` and `r-cran-curl` so you can _at least_ save yourself that step and then just install `rvest` from CRAN.

Comment: this doesn't show any output and still not able to install rvest

Comment: Sorry, mistyped: second command needs to be: `apt-cache policy r-cran-rvest`. Substitute `httr` and `curl` for `rvest` in it.  Also maybe glance at some Debian or Ubuntu tutorials (or StackOverflow questions) -- the package system is very powerful. Use it to your advantage.